# How to get wordpress password hashed from external php code?

Tags: wordpress-login

I need to hash a password using wordpress 5.5.3 method.

Wordpress uses wp_hash_password function to do it, so I think I can load the wp-load.php and class-phpass.php codes and simply use the function. However, my code doesn't work and returns a blank page:

```
$password = "abcdef";
require('/wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
require("/wp-load.php");

$hash_password = wp_hash_password($password);
echo $hash_password;
```

What's wrong? Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have something in error.log ? Did you try to improve the verbosity level or enable php error logs ?

Comment: As said NRE, impossible to help, first display errors.

Comment: I found the solution: my problem was the path in require() function. I changed /wp-includes/class-phpass.php with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/class-phpass.php' and it works. Thanks for your help!